# How to make a field UNIQUE in MySqlite?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have a table creation but I want the name of the group to be unique(in order to prevent duplicates) how can I do that? This is my query creation.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ tablemachine+" ("+
                idMaquina +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + name+ " text not null, " //I want this field unique
              ....
```

Comment: by making a field a PRIMARY KEY you will achieve that.

Comment: but the name is not a primary key, is a normal field

Comment: you can make both, the id and the name, a primary key, or you could use the unique constraints https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/unique.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add UNIQUE at the end of the column

```
`"CREATE TABLE "+ tablemachine+" ("+idMaquina +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
AUTOINCREMENT, "
+ name+ " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, " //I want this field unique`
```

Or add a constraint and your SQL should look like this

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ tablemachine+" ("+
        idMaquina +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + name+ " text not null, constraint table_name_constraint unique 
(name)) "
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add "UNIQUE" like that

```
"CREATE TABLE "+ tablemachine+" ("+idMaquina +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
+ name+ " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, " //I want this field unique
```